# Simple differential equation modelling question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

The question is: A chemical dissolves in water at a rate equal to 10% of the amount of undissolved chemical per hour. At time $t$ hours the amount of **undissolved** chemicalis $x$ grams. Initially the amount of undissolved chemicalis $6$ grams. Find the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ Now I am pretty sure it is either $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{6-x}{10} $$ or $$\frac{dx}{dt}=6-\frac{x}{10}$$ but I am unsure which one.

Comment: The 6 shouldn't be in there, it's an initial condition and doesn't have a direct effect on the behavior at a specific time t.

Comment: Even if the chemical is dissolving at a rate proportional to the amount of undissolved chemical?

Comment: Yes, because the amount of undissolved chemical is just $x$.

Comment: @MitchKnight If you're being confused thinking that the $6$ in the statement should be present somewhere in the model, then that's a good thought, but it's not supposed to be part of the differential equation, and the equation is not the whole of the model.

Comment: Alright I think I understand. Would be just $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{x}{10}$ then I guess.

Comment: Specifically the $6$ should be the value for $x(t)$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @MitchKnight If $x$ were the amount of **dissolved** chemical, then you would have $6$ in the equation, because the rate of dissolving is proportional to the amount of undissolved chemical, which would indeed by $6 - x$.

Comment: Yeah obvious now that I get it. Thank you very much.